# JavaFX access controller's synchronized method from other class

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I have a small log screen (TextFlow) in my controller class. And I wanted to print all the logs from other class to this textflow. I did the following,

```
MYAppController

@FXML
public TextFlow txtlog;

// Implement
public synchronized void setLog(String type, String log) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Text text = new Text();
            switch (type) {
                case "error":
                    text.setStyle("-fx-fill: #F5784E;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
                    break;
                case "success":
                    text.setStyle("-fx-fill: #4F8A10;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
                    break;
                case "warning":
                    text.setStyle("-fx-fill: #9F6000;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
                    break;
                case "info":
                    text.setStyle("-fx-fill: #488ed4;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
                    break;
                default:
                    text.setStyle("-fx-fill: #FFFFFF;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
                    break;
            }
            text.setText(">> " + log + "\n");
            txtLog.getChildren().add(text);
        });
    }
```

I can easily call `setLog("info", "Hello this is info!!")` , from MyController.

I wanted to print log form another class as,

```
eg. ExampleClass.java
 public MyAppController app = new MyAppController();
 app.setLog("info", "Extracting : " + currentEntry);
```

I get following error, `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Moreoverthe ExampleClass is called using `Task` like,

```
Task<Void> task1 = new Task<Void>() {
 @Override
 public Void call() {
      new Thread(new ExampleClass(param1, param2)).run();
          return null;
       }
 };
```

How can I make this work ? i.e. How can I use setLog method in Controller Class from another class (on a new thread or within the same running thread)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with multithreading: you are calling the `setLog(...)` method on the wrong instance of `MyAppController`. Presumably that class is the controller class for some FXML file: you need to get he controller from the FXMLLoader when you load that FXML file. There's not enough information in your question to provide a complete answer other than that.

Comment: The controller is the controller of some FXML file, you are correct. What sort of more info do you need ?  In between I tried with  `FXMLLoader  fXMLLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    MyAppController app = (MyAppController)fXMLLoader.getController();` but this doesnopt work either.

Comment: Well, again you can't just use the FXMLLoader to create another instance. You need the instance of the controller that is connected to the UI defined in the FXML file and displayed in your scene graph. You need to show how the two classes are related, or how the `ExampleClass` is related to the place where you actually load and display the FMXL. (Though this question has been asked many times before, just search...).